# React memo rerendering with the same props?

Tags: reactjs

having a rather simple functional Component, I would like to stop it from being rerendered if the same props are given. 
The below found online, does not seem to do the trick. Any idea what I should do instead?

props, in my case, consists of an array of objects. Some of those are nested objects, too. Is this perhaps a clue?

```
export const DataTable = React.memo(renderedTable)

export default function renderedTable(props) {
    console.log(props) // logs exactly the same props twice
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

> props, in my case, consists of an array of objects. Some of those are nested objects, too

[`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) only does **shallow comparison**.

So you need to supply your own comparison logic as a second parameter.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
}

function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
}

export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

Answer (score 1):

React.memo by default applies shallow equality comparisons - meaning that equality checks are performed on primitive values as-is but are performed on the reference (read: memory address) of the composite data structure rather than on the actual contents of that data structure. This is why using a flat props design is highly recommended.

In some cases though, nested structures may just be the only feasible design available. In this case, you may decide to pick and choose which props to compare how to do the comparisons or to defer certain comparisons to certain child components which rely on changes to those certain props to update themselves etc.

If you need to render your component based on actual prop values or some other criteria, you could supply your own implementation of the `areEqual` argument to the React.memo function. The React.memo function will then invoke that function with the `nextProps` and `previousProps` arguments. An example of an `areEqual` argument would be the `lodash.isEqual` function which could be used to do deep equality checks on those two arguments or just a few subsets thereof.

Prefer flat props designs over nested ones whenever you can.

```
const Name = React.memo(({ first = '', last = '' }) => (
    <>
        <span>{last}</span>, <span>{first}</span>
    </>
));
    
const Intro = ({age, occupation, desc = {} }) = (
    <div className="intro">
        <p>Hi!</p>
        <p>
            I am <Name { ...desc } />, the { occupation } ordinaire around here.<br />
            And I am { age } old.
        </p>
        <p>Bye!</p>
    </div>
);
    
// changes to all prop values are confirmed at the parent
const IntroMemo = React.memo( Intro, _.isEqual );
    
// changes to top level values and nested reference are confirmed at the parent
// confirmation for changes in nested prop values are deferred to the component using the nested prop.
const IntroMemoDeferred = React.memo( Intro );
```

Answer (score 0):

i know you can prevent re-rendering

1- you can use Memo Hook of React

2- you can Return false from shouldComponentUpdate

3- instead extending from "extends Component" extend from "extends PureComponent"

Notice: React's PureComponent does a shallow compare on the component's props and state. If nothing has changed, it prevents the rerender of the component. If something has changed, it rerenders the component.

Shallow Compare : https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-compare.html

can you show us a codesandbox or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your functional component, you can perform a `useEffect()`, with the dependency array provided to be your `props`. You can also take an in-depth insight from this React [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Answer (score 0):

As many have pointed out, you need to supply your own comparison logic if the props are reference types like objects, arrays, etc... because React.memo() only does shallow comparison.

First Solution: Custom helper function to deep compare 2 objects

```
// helper function to deep compare 2 objects
export const isDeepEqual = (object1: any, object2: any) => {
  const objKeys1 = Object.keys(object1);
  const objKeys2 = Object.keys(object2);

  if (objKeys1.length !== objKeys2.length) return false;

  for (var key of objKeys1) {
    const value1 = object1[key];
    const value2 = object2[key];

    const isObjects = isObject(value1) && isObject(value2);

    if (
      (isObjects && !isDeepEqual(value1, value2)) ||
      (!isObjects && value1 !== value2)
    ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
const isObject = (object: any) => {
  return object != null && typeof object === "object";
};


const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => isDeepEqual(prevProps, nextProps);
export default React.memo(renderedTable, areEqual);
```

Second Solution: Use JSON.stringify() to convert the objects into string then compare the strings

```
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => JSON.stringify(prevProps) === JSON.stringify(nextProps);
export default React.memo(renderedTable, areEqual);
```

Third Solution: Use any third-party library to do this for you (lodash, etc...)