# React native FlatList re-rendering all items even though it's memoized

Tags: react-native

I am struggling to prevent a flatlist from being re-rendered when it's parent/container component's state changes.

```
 export default ({ notes }: Props) => {
const noteSrv = new noteService()

const [selectedNoteId, setSelectedNoteId] = useState(NaN)


const noteSelected = (note: Note) => {
setSelectedNoteId(note.id)

}

const ListMemo = memo(function ({
notes,
isSelected,
}: {
notes: Note[]
  isSelected: boolean
}) {
return (
  <FlatList
    data={notes}
    renderItem={(i) => (
      <ListItem
        isSelected={false}
        note={i.item}
        noteSelected={noteSelected}
      />
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
  ></FlatList>
)
})


return  //whatever
```

As you can see, I have created a memoized version of the FlatList, but after the state of the container component changes via a call to noteSelected function, then all of the list items would be re-rendered.
How can I make the flatlist such that it only re-renders the item whose TouchableOpacity is pressed?

Edit- Even with passing a constant true to the second memo parameter (comparison parameter), the list still does re-render.

Comment: I think this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59280319/react-memo-rerendering-with-the-same-props

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the `notes` parameter. Maybe it is being recreated every time the parent component is re-rendered.

To avoid re-rendering, using the memo component is just the first step. Then, you have to ensure that all props are memoized. In your parent component, you can use `useMemo` or `useCallback` for things that are sent as props to the child component.

You can use the library `Wdyr` or view the flame chart in the React Debug tool to check why it is being re-rendered.

https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render